# K6 with DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, k6

K6 can be used with InfluxDB for data storage and Grafana for visualization.

```
k6 run --out influxdb=http://localhost:8086/myk6db script.js
```

In our project, we are using DYNAMO DB. Does K6 supports integration with DynamoDB instead of InfluxDB ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, k6 doesn't support DynamoDB. I'm not very familiar and haven't used DynamoDB, but from what I can see, I'm not sure it would be very suitable for storing time-series data and things like the metrics information k6 emits.